# overriding the delete button with visualforce page

Tags: button-overrides, delete

I need some help. I'm overriding the delete button with visualforce page. The question is : How can I get back to the **list view** or **details view** depending on from where this button was pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need two buttons, one for the list view & one for the detail page.

Then set the 'retURL' URL parameter accordingly.

Comment: is there any other way to check if the "del" link pressed from list view or delete button was pressed from the detail view to redirect accordingly? the point is to make cancel button

Comment: The cancel button on your VF page will use the value in `retURL` by default and hence go back to the correct place